# unset array keys if key is string

Tags: php, arrays, unset

i have array something like this

```
$arr  = 
    ['0' => 
        ['0' => 'zero', 
         '1' => 'test', 
         '2' =>'testphp',
         'test'=>'zero',
         'test1'=>'test',
         'test2'=>'testphp'],
    '1' => 
        ['0' => 'z', 
         '1' => 'x', 
         '2' =>'c',
         'test'=>'z',
         'test1'=>'x',
         'test2'=>'c']
        ];
```

and 0,1,2 is this same as test,test1,test2. I need remove keys where is string like test,test1,test2.
I know the way

```
foreach($arr as $a){
   unset($arr['test']);
   unset($arr['test1']);
   unset($arr['test2']);
}
```

but it is possible find keys without specifying the exact name, because i want only number keys.

Comment: `$arr = array_filter($arr, function ($key) {return is_numeric($key); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY );` if you're running PHP >= 5.6.0

Comment: But are you getting this array from a database? If so, you can tell your fetch to return only an enumerated array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be:

Assuming you know it will only have 2 layers.

```
 $arr  =
['0' =>
    ['0' => 'zero',
        '1' => 'test',
        '2' =>'testphp',
        'test'=>'zero',
        'test1'=>'test',
        'test2'=>'testphp'],
    '1' =>
        ['0' => 'z',
            '1' => 'x',
            '2' =>'c',
            'test'=>'z',
            'test1'=>'x',
            'test2'=>'c']
];

foreach($arr as $parentKey=>$arrayItem){
    foreach($arrayItem as $key=>$subArrayItem){
        if(!is_int($key)){
            unset($arr[$parentKey][$key]);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Why is it though that such arrays have been generated?

Comment: pdo generate like this array, i need hide table name when i convert to json

Answer (score 0):

edit:  after reading Valdorous answer realized it is multidimensional array.  the following should handle recursively a multi-dimensional array.

call the function (see below)

```
remove_non_numeric_keys($arr) 


function remove_non_numeric_keys($arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
        if(!is_numeric($key)) // if not numeric unset it regardless if it is an array or not
        {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }else{
            if(is_array($val) // if it is an array recursively call the function to check the values in it
            {
                remove_non_numeric_keys($val);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

This should remove only non-numeric keys.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Hope it helps